# Express router basic usage resulting in 404

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to build my express app to have routes within routes as shown below and I am getting a 404 error.

What I am trying to do is simply, route all traffic with `api` in the route to the `routes/api.js` file, then from there, based on the end of the url, depending on if its `signup` or `login`, route to the corresponding signup.js or login.js file.

Note, moving the code from routes/signup.js to routes/app.js works perfectly fine.

Has anyone gotten unexpected 404 errors under a similar set up? I appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve.

server/index.js

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));

app.use('*', (req,res) => {
   res.status(404).send('404: Not Found');
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
   console.log('api is running on port 3000');
});
```

server/routes/api.js

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.use('/signup', require('./signup'));
router.use('/login', require('./login'));

module.exports = router;
```

server/routes/signup.js

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

    router.post('/api/signup', (req, res) => {
        res.send('HELLO WORLD');
    });

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I believe you're overwriting the `app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));` with your `app.use('*', ...)`. Try swapping their places.

Comment: Note, moving the code from routes/signup.js to routes/app.js works perfectly fine.

Comment: I notice you're missing a `module.exports` from signup.js - is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, added.